# DIV Overlay Problem - Ionic V4 ( Angular)

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have the following code:

```
          <div class="input__span">
            <span [hidden]="validDocument !== false">
              Loreml lo LOR lorssssrwroee roer eruieryui!
              <app-tooltip class="input__icon-info" data="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum deleniti consectetur dignissimos, animi numquam voluptatem, ducimus aperiam sint, maiores consequuntur perspiciatis! Dicta ratione numquam repellat quia natus adipisci nihil vero?">
              </app-tooltip>
            </span>
          </div>
```

And when I use a larger z-index in app-tooltip it doesn't overlap the other elements.

is a component that displays a floating hint when we click on the icon, follow the example:
[image: Example]

Comment: Simply increasing the `z-index` won't always put elements on top of other elements. There is the concept of [the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), so without seeing the whole picture its hard to say. Can you create a snippet? or at least provide your CSS

Comment: Resolved.
Thanks